# Black Screen When Booting From .VDI Image

Tags: ubuntu, boot, virtualbox, hard-disk

I have cloned a VirtualBox machine, which runs Ubuntu 11.04 32-bit as Guest OS.

I now wish to transfer it to a new host machine running Windows Vista 32-bit. I’ve transferred the `.vdi` file and adjusted the name and memory. However when I boot it, the options to choose the Linux version came up:

- Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-10-generic
- Linux 2.6.38-10-generic(recovery mode)
- Previous Linux versions
- Memory test.

Once I chose Linux 2.6.38 a black screen just appears with an underscore at the top.

What should I do to get it to run? I don’t have my original machine near me now so I can only work with my `.vdi` image. My VB is version 4.0.10.

I have tried cloning this VDI and also assigning a new UUID and making a new guest, but I still got the black screen.

Comment: Have you tested that the image was cloned and copied without corruption? Also, do you use the same VB version (not an older one)?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same VB version and I have tested the cloned version in my original host and it worked.

Comment: It could be a problem with partition identifiers in grub menu.lst or fstab. Please try to boot from an iso-file of some rescue distribution (e.g. http://www.knoppix.net/), search for /etc/fstab and /boot/grub/menu.lst and add them to your question. We need also the output of `sudo /sbin/blkid` command.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some incompatibility between the two host systems. In the virtual machine configuration, under "System", try modifying options like "IO APIC", "PAE/NX", "VT-x/AMD-V" and "Nested Paging".